# codeigniter - listar dados relacionados

Tags: codeigniter, table, view

Olá,

Estou a tentar mostrar o nome de um canal associado a um evento através de uma FK, mas não estou a conseguir mostrar.

Model:

```
public function get_events() {
$this->db->get('events');
$this->db->join('channels', 'events.channel_id = channels.id');
$this->db->join('colors', 'channels.color_id = colors.id');
return $query = $this->db->get('events')->result();}
```

View:

```
foreach($events as $event){  
echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
    echo "<td>".$event->start." - ".$event->end."</td>";
    echo '<td class="center">'.$event->channels->name.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="center">'.$event->status_id.'</td>';
echo "</tr>";}
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não exibe os registros ou eles vem errados?

Comment: Esse return $query. Coloque: return $this->db->get('events')->result();

Comment: eu consigo visualizar tudo da 1ª entidade, events, mas se quiser mostrar da segunda entidade, channels não consigo.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Eu alteraria para o seguinte código:

```
public function get_events() {
$this->db->Select('events.*, channels.*, colors.*');
$this->db->join('channels', 'events.channel_id = channels.id');
$this->db->join('colors', 'channels.color_id = colors.id');
$this->db->from('events');
$res = $this->db->get()->result();
return $res; 
}
```

Desse modo, tu tens acesso aos dados de todas as tabelas.
Outro conselho que te dou, é como tu não especifica diferenças entre os ids, trabalhe com os `apelidos` como: `event.id as idevents` ou `channels.id as idchannels`

Espero ter ajudado.

Oss

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

Model

```
public function get_events() {
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('events');
 $this->db->join('channels', 'events.channel_id = channels.id');
 $this->db->join('colors', 'channels.color_id = colors.id');
 return $this->db->get()->result();
 }
```

Controller

```
public function pagina() {
    $this->load->model('evento_model', 'evento');
    $dados['events'] = $this->evento->get_events();
    $this->load->view("suapaginadeview.php", $dados);
}
```

View

```
foreach($events as $event){  
 echo '<tr class="odd gradeX">';
 echo "<td>".$event->start." - ".$event->end."</td>";
 echo '<td class="center">'.$event->channelname.'</td>';
 echo '<td class="center">'.$event->status_id.'</td>';
 echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Desse modo, você tem acesso a todos os dados das tabelas da consulta(Se tiver algum campo da tabela com o mesmo nome você terá que usar apelidos na consulta).